# Workday's Put_Student_Award_Item throws "The task submitted is not authorized"

Tags: soap, mule, workday-api

I have a suite of tests that execute several web service operations in Workday. A few days ago, one test related to the started failing with the error message **"The task submitted is not authorized"**. As stated in the title, the test is **Put Student Award Item** from the **Financial Aid** module. A googling suggested that there might be an issue with the user permissions. I haven't done any changes myself. I do have access to the Workday UI but I'm not familiar with it since I've only interacted with the web services. Can someone point me out the specific path to editing the user access for this particular operation? Any screenshot will be helpful too. If needed, I can provide more details of my Workday account configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that the username you use has not got the right security permissions to execute the API operation. 
You need to ask your security administrator to allow the security group assigned to your user to be added to the domain Set Up: Student Award Items

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred usually when you don't have access request of this API. You can contact workday admin.